# Replace fields values in a string

Tags: php

I want to replace fields values that I get from a database query as an array of objects in a string like this:

```
"My name is {name} and I live in {city}."
```

I found the following solution but only works when I replace the values with normal strings, not with an object property:

```
preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+)\}/', "$row->\\1", $myString)
```

I get this error: *Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string*.

Why it can't evaluate $row->fielname?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked

> Why it can't evaluate `$row->fielname?`

for the following line of code:

```
preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+)\}/', "$row->\\1", $myString)
```

To better understand that, take a look at the string in question:

```
"$row->\\1"
```

Taking the rules of PHP double quoted string variable substitution into account, it will result in the following *before* the function is called:

```
***contents of the variable $row as string*** . '->\1'
```

If `$row` can not be converted to string (which can happen with objects), this will create a fatal error.

If `$row` contains the number `42` it will be this:

```
preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+)\}/', '42->\\1', $myString)
```

Hope this example is useful.

What you probably want to do is the following:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\{([a-z]+)\}/', function($groups) use ($row) {
    return $row->{$groups[1]};
}, $myString);
```

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed on this, PHP evaluates the string before the function is called. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes PHP needs to evaluate that before calling the function, because only parameters - not expressions - are passed to a function. That is the same in nearly any computer language I know. So you can say this is common and nothing PHP specific. Just FYI. So in case you do some javascript or so, it's the same.